# How can I add external python modules in runtime?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to load a torch model, in order to do this, the model `.pt` needs two modules.

In my code I have the following structure:

```
src
  __init__.py
   ....
```

I am trying to add that two modules to src in runtime with `sys.path.insert(0, path)` but doesn't work, it only works if I copy the modules at the same level that src like

```
module_a
src
```

the problem is that I don't want to set this code in the code base of that application I only want to load it from an external folder.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: After updating sys.path are you then doing an import?

Comment: No, I cannot do that, the prolem comes from pytorch in torch.load, really I don't know how works.